# Kivy display speed for data calculation visualization

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib, plot, kivy

For a university project, I need to create an application to display interactive plot containing a lot of points (order of 100,000 to 1,000,000 points).

So I have to process the data and then display it. Building for the moment the interface with kivy / kivy garden, I am testing the calculation time and the display speed. To do that, I simply compute a for loop when refreshing the graph.

The problem is in the case of 500,000 points for example, the display time is approximatly 8-9 sec, which is quite high because tools for zooming, move the graph or some user input and some calculations are missing ! Do you have any advice or do you know how to optimize the following code to speed up a bit the app ?

Here is the code :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time


from kivy.core.window import Window 
Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1) 
Window.size = (960, 540) 


kv = """
#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition

<Manager>:
    transition: SlideTransition()

    StartPage:
        name: 'StartPage'

    SecondPage:
        name: 'SecondPage'

<StartPage>:

    canvas:

        Color:
            rgba: 0.1, 0.1, 1, 0.7

        Rectangle:
            pos: 0, 11*root.height/12
            size: root.width, root.height/12

        Rectangle:
            pos: 0, 0
            size: root.width, root.height/12


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.width, root.height


    Button:
        size_hint: 0.15, 0.08
        pos_hint: {'left': 0, 'top': 1 }
        text: 'Go to Second Page'
        on_release:
            root.manager.current = 'SecondPage'

    Button:
        size_hint: 0.15, 0.08
        pos_hint: {'right': 1, 'bottom': 1 }
        text: 'Quit'
        on_release: app.stop()


    Label:
        text: 'Start Screen'
        font_size: '20sp'
        color: 0,0,0,1
        pos_hint:{'x': 0.42, 'y': 0.46 }



<SecondPage>:
    box: box

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        id: box
        size_hint: 0.8, 0.75
        pos_hint:{'x': 0, 'y': 0.1 }

    Button:
        text:'Start Menu'
        font_size: 20
        bold: True
        size_hint: 0.15, 0.08
        pos_hint: {'left': 0, 'top': 1 }
        color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'StartPage'

    Button:
        text:'Update'
        font_size: 20
        bold: True
        size_hint: 0.15, 0.08
        pos_hint: {'x':0.8, 'y': 0.5 }
        color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        on_press: root.Update()
"""

Builder.load_string(kv)

# Start Page
class StartPage(Screen):      
    pass

#Second Page
class SecondPage(Screen):
    box = ObjectProperty(None)


    def add_plot(self, N):

        phase = np.random.normal(-np.pi/2, +np.pi/2)
        noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, N)
        nbr = np.linspace(0,1,N)
        func = 0.01*noise+np.sin(nbr/0.05+phase)

        plt.plot(nbr,func,label='Line1',color='r')
        plt.ylabel('Sinus')
        plt.xlabel('Range')
        plt.grid(True)
        self.fig1 = plt.gcf()

        return self.fig1

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        plt.cla()
        self.box.clear_widgets()
        self.fig1 = SecondPage.add_plot(self,10)
        self.box.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(self.fig1))

    def Update(self):
        start = time.process_time()
        N = int(2**19)
        # test = 0.0
        for i in range(N):
            test = i/10+np.cos(i/(i+1)*2)

        print("Number of points in the plot : ",N)
        print("boucle for : ",test)
        print("\nElapsed Time : ", time.process_time() - start)
        plt.cla()
        self.box.clear_widgets()
        self.fig1 = SecondPage.add_plot(self,N)
        self.box.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(self.fig1))


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class MyNewApp(App):
    title = "Matplolib - plot Update"

    def build(self):
        return Manager()    

MyNewApp().run()
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: This is probably mostly a matplotlib problem, it simply isn't that fast to draw so many points. You probably want to use a dedicated efficient plotting tool, but I don't know what's the best option.

If these are points in a 2d graph, consider using e.g. `hexbin` instead to show density. With so many points, it seems likely that most will be overlapping in which case you're both wasting time plotting stuff that can't be seen, and providing a bad visualisation that visually misrepresents the point density.

Comment: Ok thanks. So I will look for plotting tool or other method to show the points. Do you know if some method exist to reduce the number points whitout loosing to much information about the data and/or change the number of points dynamically with a zoom ?

Comment: It really depends on exactly what information you want to show, and what interactivity you want. As I already said, I would lean towards using a density plot by default.